# Client/Server UDP Program debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, udp, client-server

I'm trying to debug my Client-Server UDP program to see what it is doing but when I get to the .receive() method (in either the client or the server code) the break point disappears and the step-into/step-over buttons turn gray. What I see next to the .receive() method call is a little white arrow that says "debug call stack" when I hover over it. What exactly is happening?

Has it something to do with the fact that it's a blocking call? If so how do I get past beyond this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call is blocked on that line, waiting for a read.

You can place another breakpoint right after that specific line. It will break after the `receive()` is done.

The block is probably native, so you can't really debug it. However, if you never get to the second breakpoint, you know that there is problem ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting that to be the next alternative. Time to give it a try.

Comment: Yep, I'm not able to get to the next breakpoint. Step functions are all gray. Darn!

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix the bug. This helped me "...However, if you never get to the second breakpoint, you know that there is problem". So for that I thank you.

Comment: BTW, I was wondering, is it mandatory that you have to use multi-threading to implement GO_BACK_N for an RDT packet, or can it be done in a single thread?